# Error instanciando otras clases (en arrays) desde una clase padre

Tags: c#, class

Les paso el diseño de las clases. Soy novato en esto y la duda se las voy a mostrar luego de que vean el código:

Así lo instancio en mi main program:

```
allTrades = new tipoTradesCT(16, 8, 16,"", "" );  // 


public class tipoTradesTrap
{
    public    int tradeNbr;
    public string tradeName;

    public    int EntryBar;
    public string EntryTime;
    public double EntryPrice;

    public    int ExitBar;      
    public string ExitTime;
    public double ExitPrice;
    public string tradeFlag;

    public   trap   tradeTrap;

    public tipoTradesTrap(int sizeOrdTrade, int sizeTrapTrade)
    {
        this.tradeNbr           = -1;
        this.tradeName          = "";

        this.EntryBar           =  0;
        this.EntryTime          = "";
        this.EntryPrice         =  0;

        this.ExitBar            =  0;
        this.ExitTime           = "";
        this.ExitPrice          =  0;

        this.tradeTrap  = new trap(sizeTrapTrade);      
    }
}


public class tipoTradesCT
{
    // ************************************************************************
    // ************************************************************************     
    private   int   sizeTrade;

    public string   Descripcion;
    public string   LastActivity;

    public tipoTradesTrap[] trades;


    private string[] eExcludeTrades;    
    private string[] eIncludeTrades;    

    // Constructor
    public tipoTradesCT(int sizeTrade, int sizeOrdTrade, int sizeTrapTrade,string inTrades, string exTrades)
    {
        this.sizeTrade          = sizeTrade;
        this.trades             = new tipoTradesTrap[sizeTrade];

        for (int xx=0 ; xx < sizeTrade ; xx++) 
            this.trades[xx] = new tipoTradesTrap(sizeOrdTrade, sizeTrapTrade);
        this.LastActivity = "*END_new_myTrades_TRADES";
    }
}

public class trap
{
    // ************************************************************************
    //  Clase Trampa, aca estan los metodos para iniciar los trades, obvio 
    //  que solo trades con trampas de precio
    // ************************************************************************     
    public int      barDesde;
    public int      barHasta;
    public string   Tendencia;
    public double   minApoyo;
    public double   maxApoyo;
    public bool     myHammer;
    public int      despHammer;
    public double   hammBody;
    public double   barBody;
    public double   pricePromHigh;
    public double   pricePromLow;
    public bool     okAnalisis;
    public int      pSelected;
    public string   resultAnalisisGlobal;   // Resultado del proceso de analisis de la barra y determinar el tipo de trampa

    public int[]    nPivotT;
    public int[]    brkPivotT;
    public string[] resultAnalisisTrap;     // Clasificacion del trade, todo lo de analsis y set de las trampas
    public double[] limApoyo;
    public double[] maxPivotT;
    public double[] minPivotT;      
    public double[] maxBodyPivotT;
    public double[] minBodyPivotT;      
    public string[] statPivotT;
    public int[]    barHigh;        
    public int[]    barraPivotHigh;
    public double[] BarsHigh;

    public int[]     barLow;
    public double[]  BarsLow;
    public int[]     barraPivotLow;
    public string[]  tipoTrampa;
    public string[]  tipoAnalisis;
    private double[] lim105;
    private double[] lim150;
    private double[] lim104;
    private double[] lim151;    
    private double[] TakeProfit;
    private double[] StopLoss;

    private double factor105;
    private double factor150;
    private double factor104;
    private double factor151;       


    public double[] minTrap;
    public int      maxTrap;
    public int      IdTrap;
    private int     IdTrapInt;
    public string[] Output;
    public int      IdxOutput;

    // Constructor
    public trap(int pmaxtrap)
    {
        this.maxTrap            = pmaxtrap;
        this.IdxOutput          = -1;
        this.pSelected          = -1;

        this.nPivotT            = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.brkPivotT          = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.maxPivotT          = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.limApoyo           = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.minTrap            = new double[pmaxtrap+1];

        this.minPivotT          = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.statPivotT         = new string[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.TakeProfit         = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.StopLoss           = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.maxBodyPivotT      = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.minBodyPivotT      = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.barHigh            = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.BarsHigh           = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.BarsLow            = new double[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.barraPivotHigh     = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.barLow             = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.barraPivotLow      = new    int[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.tipoTrampa         = new string[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.tipoAnalisis       = new string[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.Output             = new string[(pmaxtrap*2)+1];
        this.resultAnalisisGlobal= "";
        this.resultAnalisisTrap = new string[pmaxtrap+1];
        this.okAnalisis         = false;
        this.factor105  = 1.05;
        this.factor150  = 1.50;
        this.factor104  = 1.04;
        this.factor151  = 1.51;                 
        // Index de la trampa en curso
        this.IdTrap     = 0;
        this.IdTrapInt  = -1; // valor inaccesible que controla la posicion de la trmapa

        this.minApoyo       = 0;
        this.maxApoyo       = 0;
        this.pricePromHigh  = 0;
        this.pricePromLow   = 0;
        this.myHammer       = false;
        this.despHammer     = 0;
        this.hammBody       = 0;
        this.barBody        = 0;
        this.barDesde       = 0;
        this.barHasta       = 0;

        //for (int xi = 0; xi < (pmaxtrap*2); xi++) this.Output[xi] = "*END";
        //for (int xi = 0; xi < this.maxTrap; xi++)

        for (int xi = 999999; xi < (pmaxtrap*2); xi++) this.Output[xi] = "*END";
        for (int xi = 999999; xi < this.maxTrap; xi++)
        {   

            this.nPivotT[xi]            =  0;
            this.brkPivotT[xi]          =  0;
            this.maxPivotT[xi]          =  0;
            this.minPivotT[xi]          =  0;
            this.minTrap[xi]            =  0;
            this.limApoyo[xi]           =  0;
            this.maxBodyPivotT[xi]      =  0;
            this.minBodyPivotT[xi]      =  0;               
            this.statPivotT[xi]         = "";
            this.TakeProfit[xi]         =  0;
            this.StopLoss[xi]           =  0;

            this.barHigh[xi]            =  0;
            this.barraPivotHigh[xi]     =  0;
            this.barLow[xi]             =  0;
            this.barraPivotLow[xi]      =  0;
            this.lim104[xi]             =  0;
            this.lim105[xi]             =  0;
            this.lim150[xi]             =  0;
            this.lim151[xi]             =  0;
            this.tipoTrampa[xi]         = "";
            this.tipoAnalisis[xi]       = "";
            this.resultAnalisisTrap[xi] = "";
        }
    }
```

El proceso cancela en tiempo de ejecucion cuando ejecuta :

> this.tradeTrap  = new trap(sizeTrapTrade);  ( Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array ), lo se porque si elimino esa linea el proceso no
>   cancela.

Pero si ejecuto esto en un programa comun como (ya lo probé):

`trap myTrap = new trap(16)`  Y FUNCIONA

Tengo seguro un problema con los objetos pero no tengo ni idea de que tengo mal ...

Clase trap agregada, como veran elimine el llenado de los arrays ... par aevitar algun problema y solo declare los atributos de la clase.

Comment: Trap es una clase? donde esta?

Comment: Pero falta de agregar tu clase Trap a la pregunta.

Comment: Clase añadida, como comente previamente cuando instancio esta clase desde el programa principal, lo hace sin problemas, para mi el problema esta en una declaracion de las clases principales, pero no tengo ni idea de cual es el error

Comment: Estás declarando las clases dentro del método main??

Comment: Lo hago acá allTrades = new tipoTradesCT(16, 8, 16,"", "").  La clase principal declara las otras clases dentro de la clase principal

Comment: Ejecute tu codigo y no me dio error.

Comment: Gracias Ramiro, es un dato, quiza sea un error de NinjaTrader ( tiene un compilador integrado de Visual Studio ).